Visualization of Bitwise Difference of Audio Files
In Linux, I need to visualize the bitwise difference between two audio files (left and right channel), in a way so that I can understand (approximately) when they are identical, and when they are different.
The tools I use just portray the side-by-side bitwise difference byte by byte, but I need a visualization of the full files.
Is there a utility I can use for this?

No utility, but you could do it in Python relatively easily:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import scipy.io.wavfile as wf

rate, data = wf.read("file.wav")
lchannel, rchannel = data[:,0], data[:,1]
diff = lchannel != rchannel
plt.plot(diff)


This looks promising but I am struggling to get a plottable diff out of the lchannel/rchannel. The structure is
(44100, array([[ 0,  1],        [ 0, -1],        [ 0,  0],        ...,        [ 1,  3],        [-6, -2],        [ 4,  1]], dtype=int16)) and lchannel != lchannel doesn't help. I am trying difflib but in vain. Any directions?

I amended the answer to include an example of using scipy.io.wavfile.read.

Thank you! What version of python understands the rchannel != lchannel ?

This is using numpy arrays - != on numpy arrays will perform elementwise comparison.
